# Can't see appointments and contacts in Outlook for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar, contacts, microsoft-outlook-2011

I'm a recent Mac convert (MacBook Pro) and I'm struggling with the calendar and contacts in Outlook 2011.

- **Calendar**: When I'm in the calendar I can't see any of my appointments or meetings.  The only way I can view these is by going to "Tools" and then "My Day". How do I view all my appointments and meetings in the weekly and monthly views?
- **Contacts**:  I've added a number of contacts, but when I got the the "Contacts" tab nothing shows up. The only way for me to view a contact is to do a search. Just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your calender is checked in the sidebar. If you don't have a sidebar, choose **View** > **Navigation Pane**.

[image]

Same deal with contacts. Is the box checked?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, William.  I just fixed my contacts issue by pure luck.  I don't see those check boxes on here.  When I'm in my calendar, all I see is "smart folders," but the icon to add a new calendar isn't available.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Outlook Preferences → General → Under "Folder List", UNCHECK "Hide On My Computer folders"
2. Go to View menu → CHECK "Navigation Pane"

Address Book folder should appear in the navigation pane when you lick on the Contacts tab.

Calendar folder will also appear in the navigation pane when you lick on the Calendar tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found it was something simple.
In the calendar window, look on the left panel under "Meeting, Appointment, New" and find the "Calendar" checkbox with the down arrow selector. This is where you can choose to show specific categories of calendar items and hide others. You will need to AT LEAST have "No category" checked in order to see events that you've created (even if you haven't selected an event category when creating).